# Complex SQL join Query according to given structure

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have two tables `posts` and `category_relationships`. I need to get bit complex results set out of that according to following logic.

**posts table**

```
id   |      post  
-----|------------------------------|
1000 | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet   | 
1001 | consectetur adipiscing elit  | 
1002 | sed do eiusmod tempor  ut    | 
1004 | abore et dolore magna aliqua |
```

**category_relationships table**

```
post_id    cat_id  
---------|---------|
   1000  |   201   | 
   1000  |   202   | 
   1000  |   211   | 
   1001  |   201   | 
   1001  |   211   | 
   1002  |   202   | 
   1002  |   212   |
```

First I will try to explain my category structure. I have three level structure as bellow. (to make it simple, I am not including any category table here)

```
flight [level 1] [ID : 100]
    - class      [level 2] [ID : 200]
        -- economy  [level 3] [ID : 201]
        -- business [level 3] [ID : 202]
        -- first    [level 3] [ID : 203]
    - alliance   [level 2] [ID : 210]
        -- star     [level 3] [ID : 211]
        -- oneworld [level 3] [ID : 212]
        -- skyteam  [level 3] [ID : 213]
```

**Now the algorithm:**

I need to get all the posts tagged as `flight` category or any child/children according to following rules.

I need to exclude the posts tagged as `economy` (ID:201);

1. However, it should still be in the result set if one of its siblings(`business` or `first`) were tagged.
2. It should not consider the posts where `alliance` or its child/children were tagged IF `economy` also tagged in the same posts

Please note that I can get the category ids according to structure and use them on the query.

**My approach so far:**

```
SELECT posts.ID FROM posts  
LEFT JOIN category_relationships AS tt1 ON (posts.ID = tt1.post_id) 
WHERE tt1.cat_id IN (100,200,201,202,203,210,211,212,213) 
AND posts.ID NOT IN ( SELECT post_id FROM category_relationships WHERE cat_id IN (201) )
```

But here the issue is it is removing all the posts which is tagged as `economy`. However it is not fulfilling the rule number 1.

Ideal result set would be like bellow;

```
1000 - rule number 1
1002 - anyway no `economy` tagged
```

Not including:

```
1001 - rule number 2
1004 - no tagged
```

Hope you have clear idea about the issue and any help would be really appreciating.

Comment: "the issue is it is removing all the posts which is tagged as economy" - Why is that an issue? It's a requirement - "I need to exclude the posts tagged as economy (ID:201)"

Comment: @PaulSpiegel sorry for confusion, actually as per the line above it should fulfill the two rules as I mention in the body .

Comment: I figured that out.. But it wasn't obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So one of your conditions is "It has not category 201 OR it has category 202 or 203". You are missing that OR condition `OR tt1.cat_id IN (202, 203)`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT posts.ID FROM posts  
JOIN category_relationships AS tt1 ON (posts.ID = tt1.post_id) 
WHERE tt1.cat_id IN (100,200,201,202,203,210,211,212,213) 
AND (
    posts.ID NOT IN ( SELECT post_id FROM category_relationships WHERE cat_id IN (201) ) 
  OR
    tt1.cat_id IN (202, 203)
  )
```

Note that your LEFT JOIN makes no sense and will be converted by the engine to an INNER JOIN.

However - I would write the query the following way:

```
SELECT posts.ID
FROM posts  
JOIN category_relationships AS tt1 ON posts.ID = tt1.post_id
WHERE tt1.cat_id IN (100,200,201,202,203,210,211,212,213) 
GROUP BY posts.ID
HAVING SUM(tt1.cat_id = 201) = 0
    OR SUM(tt1.cat_id = 202) > 0
    OR SUM(tt1.cat_id = 203) > 0
```

Comment: OR condition make sense, I think that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good candidate for `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT cr.post_id
FROM category_relationships cr
GROUP BY cr.post_id
HAVING SUM(cr.tag_id = 100) > 0 AND        -- flight
       (SUM(cr.tag_id = 201) > 0 OR        -- economy  
        SUM(cr.tag_id IN (202, 203)) > 0   -- business/first
       ) AND
       NOT (SUM(cr.tag_id = 201) > 0 OR    -- economy 
            SUM(cr.tag_id IN (210, 211, 212, 213) = 0  -- alliance
           );
```

This might be easier to follow with flags:

```
SELECT cr.post_id
FROM (SELECT cr.*,
             (cr.tag_id = 100) as is_flight,
             (cr.tag_id = 201) as is_economy,
             (cr.tag_id in (202, 203)) as is_first_business,
             (cr.tag_id IN (210, 211, 212, 213)) as is_alliance
      FROM category_relationships cr
     ) cr
GROUP BY cr.post_id
HAVING SUM(is_flight) > 0 AND
       (SUM(is_economy) > 0 OR  
        SUM(is_business_first) > 0
       ) AND
       NOT (SUM(is_economy) > 0 OR  
            SUM(is_alliance) > 0 
           );
```

Answer (score 0):

move your condition from where clause to ON clause

```
SELECT posts.ID FROM posts  
LEFT JOIN category_relationships AS tt1 ON (posts.ID = tt1.post_id) 
and tt1.cat_id IN (100,200,201,202,203,210,211,212,213) 
AND posts.ID NOT IN ( SELECT post_id FROM category_relationships WHERE cat_id IN (201) )
```

Comment: @janitgchinthana your opening remarks are contradictory, so we can't know